# How to find duplicate rows between two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with the same schema. One main table contains all data, and one sub table only a few entries.

My goal is to send an update to the main table, **only** for the rows that exists in both tables.

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT id FROM main_table WHERE main_table.somefields = sub_table.somefields;
UPDATE main_table set active = false WHERE id IN (<ids from query above>);
```

Is that possible, especially in one statement?

Comment: review Multiple-table syntax: - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports multi-table UPDATE syntax (though this is non-standard and not all SQL implementations support this):

```
UPDATE main_table
JOIN sub_table USING (somefield1, somefield2, ...)
SET main_table.active = false;
```

By doing an inner join, only rows that have matches will be affected.

If the fields you join on may be NULL, you'll have to decide if that means they are "equal" if they are NULL in both tables. Normally, `NULL = NULL` is not true in any implementation of SQL. But there's a special comparison operator that accounts for that.

In MySQL, this operator is [`<=>`, the NULL-safe equality operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to). This operator works the same as `=` but `NULL = NULL` is true.

```
UPDATE main_table
JOIN sub_table 
  ON  main_table.somefield1 <=> sub_table.somefield1
  AND main_table.somefield2 <=> sub_table.somefield2
SET main_table.active = false;
```

MySQL's `<=>` is their own invented operator.
In standard SQL, this operator is spelled out as `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`. Just in case other folks reading this are using brands that implement the standard syntax.

Comment: What if some of the joining fields can be `NULL`? I  just noticed that the approach works in general, but of eg `somefield2` is null in *both* tables, it does not work!

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to [provide a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you ask a code question — so you can describe the cases you need the solution to account for, and folks who answer can make sure their solution covers those cases.

Comment: For SQL questions in particular, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Well, at time of writing I did'n know that some of the fields could be `NULL`.